# How do I simulate inspect element results in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am being unable to bring the changes made in inspect element to the main theme in WordPress. I want to make the overlay color transparent and have changed the code to

```
/* THE OVERLAY COLORS WHICH WILL SHOW IN FRONT OF BACKGROUND IMAGES*/
.overlay-layer-wrap {
background: transparent
}
 .overlay-layer-2 {
  background: transparent;
}
```

but it's not taking. help!

Answer (score 0):

Your css uses cache, to refresh it, ether add version to it, or use shift + f5 to refresh the chashe as well.

To include version of style, you gotto `style.css?v=01` this will refresh width version.

---

If that doesnt work, that means you are giving css to wrong element, or assigning element to wrong css. Eather way, you can hardcode it in your div using style='yourstyle' this will take priority than css, so if you have style html tag with bg color and css with bg color, it will take priority.